# Rails > Devise password encryption

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to implement a method to allow password to be changed from another service outside devise anyhow.

```
# Profile password change
def change_password(oldpass, newpass)
    pepper  = nil
    cost    = 10

    # Encrypt plain text passwords
    encrypt_old     = ::BCrypt::Password.create("#{oldpass}#{pepper}", :cost => cost).to_s

    # Validate old
    if self.encrypted_password == encrypt_old
        encrypt_new     = ::BCrypt::Password.create("#{newpass}#{pepper}", :cost => cost).to_s
        self.encrypted_password = encrypt_new
        self.save
    else
        Logger.new("Wrong old password!")
    end
end
```

It seems i got the password encryption wrong oldpass contains a plain text of old password i need to hash it see if it matches the current password then allow new password to be stored. However all that i'm getting is wrong password.

Reworked:

```
def change_password(oldpass, newpass)
    if valid_password?(oldpass)
        password = newpass
        save
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

Comment: If you're using Devise, then you don't need to handle the encryption yourself. Devise uses bycrypt by default: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L174

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to encrypt the password yourself, if you are in the application or in Rails console.

Just update the user following way and Devise will take care of it itself.

```
user.password = new_password
user.save
```

Devise will then encrypt the password and store it. You just need to ensure that `user.password_confirmation` is `nil`. If `password_confirmation` is anything else, it will be matched against `password`.

**EDIT**

You can check the existing password with: `user.valid_password?(old_password)`

Comment: Ok that's pretty neat however the reason i wanted to encrypt it first is: I have 3 fields 1 for old password and 2 for new password.  

I need to see if the old password they entered matched the old password stored in the model and if it does then store the new password else throw a error flash message.

Comment: OK, I updated my my answer with checking if existing password is correct.

Comment: Look at my original post i added the updated method. Even tho method returns true it does not actually change the password.

Comment: Sorry it works I forgot I need to say self.save etc. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

With Devise, you don't need to handle using bcrypt yourself. By default, it handles this and the change password method. You can look at source [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L174) or just look in `config/intitalizers/devise.rb` in your Rails app.

Also, if you use the `#update_with_password` method provided by Devise, then you can pass it a hash like this:

```
{ :current_password => 'pass', :password => 'pass_new', :password_confirmation => 'pass_new' }
```

Or you can omit `:password_confirmation` if you don't want the user to have to provide a confirmation.

EDIT: I used the wrong field; it should have been 'current_password' instead of 'old_password'.

Here's the method in question in the source for Devise:

```rb
  # Update record attributes when :current_password matches, otherwise returns
  # error on :current_password. It also automatically rejects :password and
  # :password_confirmation if they are blank.
  def update_with_password(params, *options)
    current_password = params.delete(:current_password)

    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end

    result = if valid_password?(current_password)
      update_attributes(params, *options)
    else
      self.assign_attributes(params, *options)
      self.valid?
      self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
      false
    end

    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end
```

[View on GitHub](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L53-L75)

Comment: This gives Can't mass-assign protected attributes: old_password by update_with_password

Comment: mass asign error is being thrown because the fields are not accessible – the model needs to have `attr_accessible :old_password`. I do wonder however, is `old_password` an actual field that gets written into the database?

Comment: The mass-assign error shouldn't happen, it was because it should have been `current_password`. This will tell Devise to validate the old password, then make changes in one line of code.